# JavaScript Sort key value pair object based on key

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

I have an array of objects as shown below

```
[{
    "data1": "-",
    "data2": "-",
    "data3": "test",
    "data4": "20.0¢/min"
},
{
    "data1": "-",
    "data2": "-",
    "data3": "test",
    "data4": "20.0¢/min"
},
{
    "data1": "-",
    "data2": "-",
    "data3": "test",
    "data4": "20.0¢/min"
}
```

]

I would like to rearrange the key value pairs in each object based on its key name and the rearranged array would look like

```
[{
         "data3": "test",
         "data1": "-",
         "data4": "20.0¢/min",
         "data2": "-"


     },
     {
         "data3": "test",
         "data1": "-",
         "data4": "20.0¢/min",
         "data2": "-"
     },
     {
         "data3": "test",
         "data1": "-",
         "data4": "20.0¢/min",
         "data2": "-"
     }
 ]
```

what is the best way to achieve this in JavaScript

Comment: can you show us what you already have tried?. this is good to include aswell

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
const arr = [{
    "data1": "-",
    "data2": "-",
    "data3": "test",
    "data4": "20.0¢/min"
},
{
    "data1": "-",
    "data2": "-",
    "data3": "test",
    "data4": "20.0¢/min"
},
{
    "data1": "-",
    "data2": "-",
    "data3": "test",
    "data4": "20.0¢/min"
}
]

const rearrangedArr = arr.map(obj => ({data3: obj['data3'], data1: obj['data1'], data4: obj['data4'], data2: obj['data2']}))

console.log(rearrangedArr)
```